# Replacing a date pattern

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I've previously asked a similar question about replacing a string pattern in R. This is however a little more sophisticated although I feel I'm almost there. I've the following column on `dataraw`:

```
> head(dataraw$date)
date
2/23/2015     
2/23/2015     
2/23/2015     
3/23/2015     
3/23/2015     
3/23/2015
```

I would like to replace all strings with pattern `2/dd/yyyy` for `February`, `3/dd/yyyy` for `March` and so on.

I'm looking for the general code line to achieve this. The following line, for example, will replace the whole column into `February` which is not what I want:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(c("2/22/2012"), "^2.+", "February"
```

Any suggestions? Hope I can at least be set on the right track!

Comment: What is the format/type of `date` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

```
format(as.Date(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%b')
#[1] "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar"
```

Or to get the full month name (as @Wiktor Stribiżew clarified),

```
format(as.Date(df$date, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%B')
#[1] "February" "February" "February" "March"    "March"    "March"
```

Comment: Then, maybe `format(as.Date(x, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%B')` (with `%B`)

Comment: Oh right. Totally missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can as well use `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)

dtime <- c("1/23/2015", "2/23/2015", "3/23/2015", "4/23/2015", "5/23/2015")                         
dtime
#[1] "1/23/2015" "2/23/2015" "3/23/2015" "4/23/2015" "5/23/2015"

# format it as lubridate date object
dtime <- mdy(dtime)

dtime <- month(dtime, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
data.frame(dtime)

#      dtime
# 1  January
# 2 February
# 3    March
# 4    April
# 5      May
```

Hope that helps.